# How to compare the results of two tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compare the following:

-id field to id field comparison across the same tables

-Number of results received on the same day

-are all fields data matching between those tables for that day for that id field

it should be something like finding a duplicate entry for a specific field in this case I used an id field for example but not in the same table from a different table thats all

If someone could provide an example/script it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask], post a [mcve] including the table DDL, sample data, expected output.

Comment: do you want to find the rows which are not in both or use count and group by to compare the number of records for different categories? What do you expect to find?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_comparison.htm

Comment: I edited the body of my question to provide some more information of what I am looking for. Thank you all for providing any help with what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If columns are same in both the tables then you can simply use

```
(SELECT * FROM Table_A
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Table_B)
MINUS
(SELECT * FROM Table_A
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM Table_B);
```

If columns are different just select common columns in the select query.

Union will give you all data of table_A and table_b and will not include duplicates.
Intersect will give you common data of tabel_A and table_B

Finally using Minus will give you all data which is either not available in table_A or table_B.

If you are expecting some different dataset then mention that in you question.

Comment: This solution doesn't allow us to distinguish which tables produce the different rows. So it does produce a delta but not a very helpful one. Also it doesn't address the distributed name of the Seeker's question : *"compare specific objects results between two databases "*

Comment: I edited my question to provide a little bit more detail of what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you.